# Warning "mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in db_connection.php on line 7 Failed

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I looked around but i honestly have no idea what im doing, i had like 4 error when i started but i got it down to one.  Ive tried to changed the username but that didnt really help.

```
   <?php
    $mysql_username = "root";
    $mysql_password = "";
    $db_name = "bvruggg";
    $server_name = "192.168.104.1";

    $conn = mysqli_connect($server_name, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $db_name);

    ?>
```

im using xampp to host this and i made a database and a table to the best i could following the guide I found

Comment: check if the server is running (service) and also check the **port** it is running test account data with mysql.exe

Comment: both work fine i have it ruing on a domain, if that makes scene.

Comment: no when all is runnign and mysql.exe connects, you have soemwhere else a problem and should update with the code you have, also enable error reporting to find evnetual problemws.

Comment: Are you sure you're using right server name? Also - did you check if the correct ports are open? [This post](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/595/how-to-solve-xampp-mysql-error-2002-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it) has few answers that could help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using XAMPP, try changing your server_name value to localhost:

```
<?php
    $mysql_username = "root";
    $mysql_password = "";
    $db_name = "bvruggg";
    $server_name = "localhost";

    $conn = mysqli_connect($server_name, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $db_name);
?>
```

Comment: i changed it to local host and i didnt get an error on my local host but now my website is displaying the xampp dashboard